# Is it Possible to Convert Azure Classic VM dynamic IP (VIP) to Static IP (VIP)?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-vm-role

I have a Classic Azure VM whose current public ip is dynamic. I want this same ip to convert to Static. Is it possible? 
If Yes, How?

Answer (score 1):

> I want this same ip to convert to Static. Is it possible?

Yes,you can reserve the IP address to achieve that.

Reserved IPs can be used only as a VIP, ensuring that the IP address for the cloud service remains the same, even as resources are shut down or stopped (deallocated).

To reserve the IP address of a cloud service TestService in the Central US location, run the following PowerShell `(Classic)` command:

```
New-AzureReservedIP –ReservedIPName MyReservedIP –Location "Central US" -ServiceName TestService
```

You can see more details about converting existing dynamic IPs used as a VIP to a reserved IP address in [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip#reserve-the-ip-address-of-an-existing-cloud-service).

Comment: Hi,@Avinash patil , if this answer is helpful to you, please mark it as answer to help more people.